# How to add nohup? - Redirect stdin to program and background

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I have a program `prog` that takes stdin input like this:

```
prog < test.txt
```

But the processing takes quite a lot time, so once the input is read, it the process should background.

From this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71218/201221 I have working solution, but without `nohup`. How modify it to use `nohup` too?

```
#!/bin/sh
{ prog <&3 3<&- & } 3<&0
```

Comment: You don't *need* `nohup` -- it does nothing the shell can't do on its own. See `disown`

Comment: BTW, you're using `/bin/sh` but tagging the question bash. `sh` specifies POSIX sh, not bash -- does the tag mean a bash-only answer is acceptable?

Comment: @Charles Duffy At best the solution should be compatible with `sh` and `bash`.

Comment: If you want POSIX sh (which would give you compatibility with both), the question should be tagged `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: ...that said, I'm not at all convinced that this is *possible* relying only on baseline POSIX sh functionality, since `nohup` closes stdin (behavior you don't want), and `disown` is a non-POSIX extension.

Comment: `prog < file.txt > ouput.txt 2>&1 & disown` should do the trick

Comment: @hek2mgl, right -- what makes this tricky is that the OP wants to invoke prog in the background *in a script*, but still allow it to read from the script's pre-redirected stdin.

Comment: Aha, got it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disown` is a shell builtin which tells bash to remove a process from its recordkeeping -- *including* the recordkeeping that forwards HUP signals. Consequently, if stdin, stdout and stderr are all redirected or closed before the terminal disappears, there's absolutely no need for `nohup` so long as you use `disown`.

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile=nohup.out            # change this to something that makes more sense.
[ -t 1 ] && exec >"$logfile" # do like nohup does: redirect stdout to logfile if TTY
[ -t 2 ] && exec 2>&1        # likewise, redirect stderr away from TTY

{ prog <&3 3<&- & } 3<&0
disown
```

If you *really* need compatibility with POSIX sh, then you'll want to capture stdin to a file (at a potentially very large cost to efficiency):

```
#!/bin/sh

# create a temporary file
tempfile=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/input.XXXXXX") || exit

# capture all of stdin to that temporary file
cat >"$tempfile"

# nohup a process that reads from that temporary file
tempfile="$tempfile" nohup sh -c 'prog <"$tempfile"; rm -f "$tempfile"' &
```

Comment: Both solutions are probably the best possible one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the following code is contained in a separate shell file:

```
#!/bin/sh
{ prog <&3 3<&- & } 3<&0
```

So, why not try just:

```
nohup the_file.sh &
```

Comment: This prints the classic "... appending output to 'nohup.out'" when `nohup` is used without `&` for backgrounding. Is any form of `nohup xxx &` possible?

Comment: @Mvorisek yes. I forgot to add the `&` at the end :)

Comment: @Mvorisek, nohup unconditionally redirects stdin away from the TTY -- that's part of its specification.